# Using LIKE queries, Foreign Keys or jsonb arrays for filtering Postgres SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, which suppose to contain relations to other tables. But I need these relations only for filtering, i.e. the relations in this case are not suppose to work as foreign key or some kind of references - I just need to search through them. It works like tags or something.
Here is the example:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."table_name" 
(
    "id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "relations" text NOT NULL,
    "some_column" text,
    "some_another_column" int4,
    "created" timestamp(6) WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT "table_name_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE,
    CONSTRAINT "owner" FOREIGN KEY ("owner") REFERENCES "public"."user" ("id") ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE,
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "public"."table_name" OWNER TO "postgres";
```

the `relations` column will contain multiple uuid keys. This column is not suppose to be `SELECT`ed, I intend to use it only for filtering. In this case I intend to use this kind of queries to select rows from **only this** table:

```
SELECT 
    id, some_column, some_another_column 
FROM 
    table_name 
WHERE 
    relations LIKE '%c56c8a4f-765a-4e1c-9638-f3736a25da17%' 
    AND owner = 'badee659-1fca-412a-bcf6-c73ecf1e65aa';
```

Of course, I will create a multicolumn `(owner,relations)` index.

Is this a good approach to perform this kind of search queries? `relations` column will contain 1 to 10 uuids per each row on the average.

Or, maybe I should create additional table, which will contain, say, one uuid for each 'relation' and FK for referencing to the `table_name` table? In this case I will use `JOIN` queries.

Or may be there are better ways? May be I should store uuids as array within `jsonb` object? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Index consideration

Using operator `LIKE` with leading `%` is not [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable.). It won't use your index, because the optimizer doesn't know how to narrow first characters from `relations` column.

### Design

It's *almost always* a bad idea to store different values in one column as a string with delimiter.

Remember that relational databases are designed for performing `JOIN` operations efficiently. In my opinion it would be better to separate that data into rows with atomic values in their columns.

### Json consideration

`json` and `jsonb` datatypes should only be taken under consideration if your columns are unpredictably changing. By saying this I mean that whenever you can (without much overhead going on) fit your model into relational one, you should **always** go for it. The same goes for `hstore`.

You could read [this blog post](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/) to grab some information to start with when considering using a mechanism for storing dynamic columns.

A little quote from that post:

> **How to decide when to use json**
>
> Use json if your data won’t fit in the database using a normal
>   relational modelling.

Credit for above blogpost goes to [@Craig Ringer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398670/craig-ringer).

Comment: > It's almost always a bad idea to store different values in one column as a string with delimiter <  
I'm sure, i will not use it any way but for search, and also, rows in this table will be deleted and inserted about 1 time per 15 selects (i.e. the rows will be selected less than 15 times average before they will be deleted and replaced with other similar rows)
Are you sure, additional table + `JOIN` search is better solution in this case?

Comment: With another table you would have a possibility to keep different uuids in different rows and a column that groups them, so that you could write a `WHERE` clause knowing only 1 value and retrieving every `uuid` from that group, without using `LIKE` expression. You could do a little benchmarking depending on your needs. Dead tuples are being cleaned/reused (`VACUUM`). `DELETE` queries can use indexes, for example in your case on a group of `uuids` to recreate them easily. Feel free to test it though, my opinion may not be the best source in this case.